# how can I access the javascript variable value in my qt-code

Tags: javascript, qt

I'm a beginner in Qt. Would someone tell me how to use the javascript variable value in qt-code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello. You should provide some code showing what you've tried, and perhaps what resources you've checked out. It would also be good to explain a bit on what scenario you're trying to do this to give your question some context.

Comment: Hello Mariano, thank you for your advice. I'm using QWebView to show a html page content. There's a variable(Let's say myVar = "test") I need to get to use in my qt code. Someone said I should use: const QVariant myvar = view->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript("myVar"); to get myVar's value, while I failed. Do you understand what I'm trying to explain?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some documentation that should answer your question:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebframe.html#evaluateJavaScript

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtwebkit-bridge.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebframe.html#addToJavaScriptWindowObject

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebframe.html#javaScriptWindowObjectCleared

Just from looking at the docs, you probably need to also call `addToJavaScriptWindowObject()`, and maybe even need to make sure that the object doesn't get cleared when the javascript finishes.

Hope that helps.